# CartThrob: Pass custom field through checkout to be email recipient

Tags: email, notification, custom-data

My client wants to set email notifications based on product. So Product A would be mailed to bob@blah.com, and Product B would be mailed to john@blah.com. They would enter the recipient in the product entry.

At first I tried passing this data through the cart as a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom_data[notification_email_recipients]" value="{notification_email_recipients}" />
```

Then created an email notification within CartThrob's notifications panel with this as the To Email:

```
{custom_data:notification_email_recipients}
```

But CartThrob sends out an email notification to:

```
 {notification_email_recipients)@blah.com
```

Which is kicked back by the email servers as undeliverable (obviously).

My question is: How can I pass a custom entry field through the shopping cart and then let CartThrob pull that field to send an email notification?

My second question is: Is there an easier way to accomplish this without passing hidden variables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this without a custom extension/module.

I had a similar scenario where different ordered products needed to be notified to various email addresses.

What I did was add a hidden product option field with a unique variable, in my case with unique values of either "xProduct" or "xEvent". This gets stored as a custom field in the order data.

The value is written to the admin email template, just output as a data field somewhere.

All order emails go to a central mailbox but I then used server side email filtering, any emails that contained the (unique) word xEvent would be cc'd to events@domain.com, and any that contained xProduct cc'd to orders@domain.com.